# redirect http and https non-www and www urls to secure www url in apache2 site.conf

Tags: http, https, debian, apache2, redirect

I want all the following urls:

```
-http://xyz.com.au
-http://www.xyz.com.au
-https://xyz.com.au
-https://www.xyz.com.au
```

to resolve to

```
https://www.xyz.com.au
```

To accomplish this I have created /etc/apache2/sites-available/xyz.conf file as follows:

```
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

    <VirtualHost *:80>

            ServerName www.xyz.com.au
            ServerAlias xyz.com.au
            Redirect permanent / https://www.xyz.com.au

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>

            ServerName www.xyz.com.au
            ServerAlias xyz.com.au

            DocumentRoot /var/www/xyz.com.au/vas_public
            DirectoryIndex index.html

            # ... SSL configuration goes here
            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/xyz/xyz.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/xyz/xyz.key

    </VirtualHost>
```

This results in the following url redirects:

```
http://www.xyz.com.au  --> https://www.xyz.com.au (responses 301, 200)

http://xyz.com.au      --> https://www.xyz.com.au (responses 301, 200)

https://www.xyz.com.au --> https://www.xyz.com.au (responses 200)

https://xyz.com.au     --> https://xyz.com.au     (responses 301, 200)
```

To try and correct the https://xyz.com.au redirect
I added the following lines directly below the SSLCertificateKeyFile ...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.vasports.com.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.vasports.com.au/$1 [NS,L,R=permanent]
```

And now I get the following results:

```
http://www.xyz.com.au   --> https://www.xyz.com.au (responses 301, 200)

http://xyz.com.au       --> https://www.xyz.com.au (responses 301, 200)

https://www.xyz.com.au  --> https://www.xyz.com.au (responses 200)

https://xyz.com.au      --> https://www.xyz.com.au//   (responses 301, 200)
```

So I have effectively fixing the https://xyz.com.au redirect but now with the added //. Why is this happening?

NOTE: my cert is for www.xyz.com.au.

I used the examples in this link for the :80 vhost permanent redirects.

```
https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL
```

Both HTTP redirects take more than 1000ms, which seems way too long, especially considering that the https://xyz.com.au --> https://www.xyz.com.au// redirect takes only about 3ms.
Is this normal behaviour?

Am I doing this incorrectly, and if so what is the correct and most responsive way to perform the redirects?

Answer (score 1):

> So I have effectively fixing the https://xyz.com.au redirect but now with the added //. Why is this happening?
>
> NOTE: my cert is for www.xyz.com.au.

If your cert is for www.xyz.com.au you can't redirect https://xyz.com.au to https://www.xyz.com.au because the browser will refused the first redirect : https://xyz.com.au do not have a valid certificate

Comment: Can this be overcome by using a wildcard certificate?

Comment: No. *.xyz.com apply only to a.xyz.com, b.xyz.com, c.xyz.com, .. and NOT to xyz.com itself BUT you can have a multi-domain certificate with xyz.com and www.xyz.com